# Want to access an external variable from js file into angular 2 ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have coded a js file to return some values to ts files, in my angular project.

```
var webGlObject = (function() { 
  return { 
    init: function() { 
      alert('webGlObject initialized');
    } 
  } 
})(webGlObject||{})
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import '../../../lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js';
import '../../../server/getSummary.js';

declare var webGlObject: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'mop-designer-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'mop-designer-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['mop-designer-dashboard.component.css'],
})

export class MopDesignerDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  debugger;
  scoreBoardList: any = [];
  breadcrumb: any = [];

  constructor() {

    /* prepare breadcrumb */
    this.breadcrumb = [
      {
        label: 'Mop Designer',
        href: '/#/mop-designer'
      }
    ];

    debugger;

    webGlObject.init();



  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('test');
  }
}
```

but declare var webGlObject: any; doesn't create any object 
and I get following error:

>
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js?fad3:339
VM292602:61 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: webGlObject is not defined
ReferenceError: webGlObject is not defined
    at new MopDesignerDashboardComponent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are creating it as a class and using as an object.
Try this:
Put following in js file:

```
var webGlObject = function() {
this.init= function() {
  alert('webGlObject initialized');}}
```

And create an instance in ts file:

```
declare var webGlObject: any;
export class YourComponent{
constructor(){
    let wegObj = new webGlObject();
    wegObj.init();
  }
}
```